# Redirects ignored after completing struts action when using Liferay behind apache proxy

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, liferay, liferay-6

I have a problem using Liferay behind Apache proxy. The issue is with redirects after completing struct action. Problem appears in build-in portlets, for example on pages: "Control Panel"->"Users" and "My Account"->"My Workflow Tasks" and probably other places. When list of users is displayed and I perform some action on a user (activate/deactivate) the action is completed successfully. But afterwards instead of returning to user list page, a user details/edit page is being displayed. Similar thing happens with performing actions on workflow tasks.

This happens only when I connect to Liferay portal through Apache proxy. When I connect directly to liferay tomcat everything works. In liferay tomcat access_logs the only meaningful difference between this two cases is the "redirect" URL parameter (there was also different refererPlid id, but it doesn't seem relevant). Anything else in the URL is identical.
And the only difference within redirect parameter was the beginning of the URL. In case of using proxy it was domain name configured in Apache virtual host and default port. In case of no Apache it has server IP and tomcat port.

```
Without apache: ...http%3A%2F%2F10.254.10.124%3A8080... or ...http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080... 
With apache: ...http%3A%2F%2Fsome.domain.eu...
```

In both cases action was successfully performed. 
Without apache there was redirect, tomcat response: "`302 -`"
With Apache user detailes/edit page was displayed, tomcat response: "`200 12762`"

I am using `liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6`.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using `mod_jk` or `mod_proxy_ajp`?

Comment: I am using mod_proxy_ajp.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was resolved using Liferay security settings in portal.properties.

```
##
## Redirect
##

#
# Set this property to "ip" or "domain" for the redirect security method. If
# set to "domain", the portal will only redirect users to domains listed in
# the property "redirect.url.domain.allowed". If set to "ip", the portal
# will only redirect to domains whose IP address resolve to an IP address
# listed in the property "redirect.url.ip.allowed".
#
#redirect.url.security.mode=domain
redirect.url.security.mode=ip

#
# Input a list of comma delimited domains which the portal is allowed to
# redirect to. Input a blank list to allow any domain.
#
redirect.url.domains.allowed=

#
# Input a list of comma delimited IPs which the portal is allowed to
# redirect to. Input a blank list to allow any IP. SERVER_IP will be
# replaced with the IP of the host server.
#
redirect.url.ips.allowed=127.0.0.1,SERVER_IP
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try replacing

```
ProxyPass /liferay ajp://localhost:8009
ProxyPassReverse /liferay ajp://localhost:8009
```

with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) ajp://localhost:8009/$1 [P]
```